# Why Log file size is not reaching there endpoint using NLog?

Tags: nlog

I set my log file size archiveAboveSize = 2048000 ie, 2048KB in target of NLog.config file. but log file size is growing until 2000KB and after creating another extension and it is happening everytime. Can anybody explain me why is this happening?

Comment: Does it archive too soon or not at all?

Comment: archiving soon but otherwise working fine.

Comment: And what is "after creating another extension"?

Comment: it start from 1kb until 2000kb but suppose to be reach 2048kb

Comment: internalLogLevel="Trace" and I am using correct nlog.config file.

Comment: For small size archive working fine like 10kb, 20kb but for large size file archive early. For example I set 1024kb but archive file is only 1000kb and same with 2048kb is archiving 2000kb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2,048,000 bytes = 2000 KB, as a kilo is 1024. So it's correct, see also:

[image]

Comment: yeah it looks like windows issue. That time I didn't check the size in properties, now got it. thanks for the explanation.